# Problema com a saída de delta<0

Tags: c

Boa noite, estou tendo problema com a saída do meu programa que imprimi na tela as raizes da equação do segundo grau.
Quando vou para a condição de:

```
if (delta<0) //Condicao caso o delta seja menor que zero
{  
    printf("Sem raiz"); //Impressao de um resultado invalido
}
```

A saída do programa fica como:

```
Sem raiz0.0000
0.0000
```

Comment: Só com isto não é possível te ajudar, coloque partes relevantes do programa: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Só com esta parte do código fica complicado. Provavelmente a parte que imprime o resultado deve estar após o if (e fora do else)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Só com a parte que você postou do código, é complicado ajudar.
A impressão que dá é que falta um `else` para mostrar os resultados apenas se o delta for zero ou mais.

Algo assim:

```
if (delta<0) //Condicao caso o delta seja menor que zero
{  
    printf("Sem raiz"); //Impressao de um resultado invalido
}
else
{
    // aqui vai o printf que mostra as raízes, que só aparecerão se
    // a condição anterior for falsa, graças ao else.
}
```